# compare string[] to string[] in for loop

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to compare 2 `strings[]` and display as checked the similar items.
It is working fine when the first list to compare has a single value but not in a list (`string[]`)

```
@functions {
    private static string[] GeoArea
    {
        get
        {
            string[] geoArea = {"Horse", "Cat", "Dog", "Dear", "Donkey", "Lamb"};
            return geoArea;
        }
    }

    string[] geoArea = GeoArea;
}

@{
    string[] blablab = {"Cat", "Dog", "Dear"};
    var results = string.Join(",", blablab);
}

@{
    for (int s = 0; s < geoArea.Length; s++)
    {
        if (results != geoArea[s])
        {
            <input class = "check_boxes" id = "@s.ToString()" name = "District" type = "checkbox" value = "@geoArea[s]"/>
            @geoArea[s]
        }
        else
        {
            <div style = "background-color: red; min-height: 50px;" >
                <input class = "check_boxes" id = "@s.ToString()" name = "District" type = "checkbox" value = "@geoArea[s]" checked = "checked"/>
                @geoArea[s]
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

The results are all items are unchurched

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly are you expecting `"Cat,Dog,Dear"` to be a match for any one of `"Horse", "Cat", "Dog", "Dear", "Donkey", "Lamb"`?

Comment: i need to display "Cat,Dog,Dear" as checked & the rest Unchecked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Contains` here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0

```
@functions {
    private static string[] GeoArea
    {
        get
        {
            string[] geoArea = {"Horse", "Cat", "Dog", "Dear", "Donkey", "Lamb"};
            return geoArea;
        }
    }
    string[] geoArea = GeoArea;
}

@{
    string[] blablab = {"Cat", "Dog", "Dear"};
}

@{
    for (int s = 0; s < geoArea.Length; s++)
    {
            <div style="@(blablab.Contains(geoArea[s]) ? "background-color: red; min-height: 50px;" : "" )" >
                <input class = "check_boxes" id="@s.ToString()" name="District" type="checkbox" value="@geoArea[s]" @(blablab.Contains(geoArea[s]) ? "checked" : "" ) />
            @geoArea[s]
            </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank was. i was trying to avoid Contains (it take a bit longer browser time) . but it look like i have to .

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain what exactly you want to compare but I think this is what you want:

```
string[] geoArea = { "Horse", "Cat", "Dog", "Dear", "Donkey", "Lamb" };
string[] blabla = { "Cat", "Dog", "Dear" };
List<string> match = new List<string>();

//Go through each entry in your blabla array
foreach(string animal in blabla)
{
    //Check if the geoArea array contains the entry 
    if (geoArea.Contains(animal))
    {
        //Add the matching entries to match List
        match.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

This will add all matching entries of your arrays to `List<string> match`.

Don't forget to add this namespace: `using System.Linq;`